# Receivetask in camunda is not working as expected

Tags: spring, camunda

We have been using camunda 7.4 version in most of our projects along with camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter 1.1.0.

We have a project where in the camunda flow we try to publish a message to a message broker which internally is consumed by another system and re-publish a new message to the same message broker. Then we trigger a receiveTask to receive that message and process further. To listen to the incoming message we use org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener and we define the message co-relation for receiveTask within the onMessage() method. But we get below error in doing so

org.camunda.bpm.engine.MismatchingMessageCorrelationException: Cannot correlate message 'ReceiveAmsharedResponse': No process definition or execution matches the parameters

We are trying to figure where the problem is? Is it in the version of camunda we are using or the problem is with the usage of receiveTask. We tried all approaches defined in https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/bpmn20/tasks/receive-task/ but no luck.

For the method createMessageCorrelation we get above error. And for other methods we get a NPE as EventSubscription/Execution  objects are null.

Sample Camunda flow receiveTask Usage is as below:

```
 <bpmn2:receiveTask id="ReceiveTask" name="Receive Task" messageRef="Message_06nl07f">
  <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_xyz</bpmn2:incoming>
  <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_190m9nx</bpmn2:outgoing>
</bpmn2:receiveTask>
......
......
<bpmn2:message id="Message_06nl07f" name="Message" />
```

And sample message co-relation code:

```
 class XYZ implements MessageListener {
 onMessage() {
    runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation("Message")
                .processInstanceBusinessKey(resourceId)
                .setVariable(ACTIVITY_RESULT, activityResult)
                .correlate();
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks,
Viswanath

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your process looks something like this:

```
O -- ( M ) -- ( M ) -- O
     send    receive
```

If the response message is send very fast, it possible that the `onMessage` and message correlation is executed before the message event subscription is persisted in the database. Basically the message arrives while the send task is stil being executed.

One way to avoid this would be to create the message subscription in parallel with sending the event:

```
O -- + -- ( M ) -- + -- O
     |    send     |
     `----( M ) --´
         receive
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to the given exception message which is :

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.MismatchingMessageCorrelationException: Cannot correlate message 'ReceiveAmsharedResponse': No process definition or execution matches the parameters
```

I assume that you correlate a message with the name `ReceiveAmsharedResponse`, but you defined a Message with a different name  for your ReceiveTask.

Changing the definition of your Message to the following should work:

```
<bpmn2:message id="Message_06nl07f" name="ReceiveAmsharedResponse" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your process looks something like this:

```
O -- ( M ) -- ( M ) -- O
     send    receive
```

This error means that a `response` was `received` "earlier" than the `request` was `sent`.
And by `sent`, I mean the whole transaction of the `send-request` process.

So, in other words, because of the fast response, there is no commited transaction in Camunda Database for the `send-request` process. Thus, when camunda processes the `response-received` process, it is not possible to correlate the `response-received` with the `send-request`.

One suggested solution is to use `Async Continuations` that Camunda offers and you might check in their [official website](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/). More specifically, you might use `Async Before` at the `send-request` level:

```
( M ) 
 send
```

`Async Before` will save the transaction in Camunda database, before the `send-request` process will begin. Τherefore, it will be possible for the `response` to be correlated.